# how to set uib-datepicker-popup opens always in day mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, directive

I have this issue with `uib-datepicker-popup` that when users opens the date picker and goes to month or year mode and closes the picker,and opens the date picker again, the picker opens in the last mode it was before being closed. How can I change behavior of `uib-datepicker-popup` to open in day mode always?

One option that I found was to set both `minMode` and `maxMode` to `day`, but doing so will prevent user from going to other modes which I don't want!

any idea is appreciated!

Here is a plunk to get you going:  [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FxdM7qRQL3r1mQuPFBFT?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to force to set date picker mode before the popup is getting displayed. In that case there is no need to specify `datepicker-options="{minMode: 'day', maxMode: 'day'}"` that will prevent the user from choosing another modes.

So, set `datepickerMode` on popup `click` event:

```
$scope.open1 = function() {
  $scope.dateOptions.datepickerMode = 'day'; //<-force to set date picker mode
  $scope.popup1.opened = true;
};
```

[**Updated demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wclqlmXH6EezoKgbU31x?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `datepickerMode` property for the `datepicker-options` directive.

The docs say

> datepickerMode C  (Default: day) - Current mode of the datepicker (day|month|year). Can be used to initialize the datepicker in a specific mode.

The datepicker has 3 modes:

> day - In this mode you're presented with a 6-week calendar for a specified month.
>   month - In this mode you can select a month within a selected year.
>   year - In this mode you are presented with a range of years (20 by default).

you can define it inline inside your markup like

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" datepicker-options="{'datepickerMode: 'day'}"></div>
```

or just pass an option object

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" datepicker-options="optionsObject}"></div>
```

Then set a `$watch` to `dt` so when the user fiddles with your picket, the watcher will reset your mode back to `day`.

```
$scope.$watch('dt', ()=>{
    $scope.dateOptions.datepickerMode = 'day';
});
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, if the user changes the `ng-model` he has to change its mode to `day` and pick a day, my problem is that if the `ng-model` doesn't change and user just navigate to year mode, other time that he opens the picker, the mode that picker opens will be year..

Comment: what if you'll watch `$scope.dateOptions.datepickerMode` instead, and change the mode if the popup in closed ?